# Inserting a blank line after change in first alphabet using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am writing a script in `bash` for an address book. Everything is working now except that I am unable to separate alphabetical records with a blank line when the alphabet changes. I  have a file which after sorting gives with awk, the output as follows:

```
Anand Anju
Anand Sanjay
Das Ajay
Deshpande Shweta
Kanetkar Ashok
Kanetkar Jyoti
Sabane Dhananjay
Sahani Surinder
```

I want to generate the output as given below;

```
Anand Anju
Anand Sanjay

Das Ajay
Deshpande Shweta

Kanetkar Ashok
Kanetkar Jyoti

Sabane Dhananjay
Sahani Surinder
```

I desire a solution using `awk`.

Comment: `perl -0777pe 's/^(.).*(?:\n\1.*)+(?=\n.)\K/\n/gm' inputf` can also help solve the pbm.

Answer (score 4):

Use `awk` to pick out the first character of the current input line. If it's different from the first character of the previous line, output a blank line. Remember the first character of this line and then output the current line.  This way you get a blank line outputted before each line if the first character changes from what it was on the previous line.

```
$ awk '{ cur = substr($0,1,1) } NR > 1 && cur != prev { print "" } { prev = cur; print }' file
Anand Anju
Anand Sanjay

Das Ajay
Deshpande Shweta

Kanetkar Ashok
Kanetkar Jyoti

Sabane Dhananjay
Sahani Surinder
```

Comment: Yesss..it worked. Thanks for the explanation too.

Answer (score 1):

Another ***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR>1 && a && substr($1,1,1)!=a{ print "" }{ a=substr($1,1,1) }1' file
```

---

- `substr($1,1,1)` - extract the 1st character from the 1st field

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{A[$1]++;if(A[$1]==1){printf("\n")}}1' FS= file
```

Comment: Nice one. Not efficient, but compact.

Answer (score 0):

We accumulate the next line into the pattern space and compare the first char of the pattern space with the first char of the last line in the pattern space.

When a match, we append one more line into the pattern space. Now in case we hit the eof, we immediately quit (`N`) command does it, that's why we don't prefix it with a `$!` to take advantage of this feature.

Else, we place a newline at the end of the block.

GNU sed is assumed.

```
sed -e '
   :a;N
   /^\(.\).*\n\1[^\n]*$/ba
   h;s/\(.*\n\).*/\1/p
   g;s/.*\(\n\)/\1/;D
' file.txt
```

---

### Results

```
Anand Anju
Anand Sanjay

Das Ajay
Deshpande Shweta

Kanetkar Ashok
Kanetkar Jyoti

Sabane Dhananjay
Sahani Surinder
```